# How to refer back to the just mentioned subject?

Tags: word-request, definite-article, generic-noun-phrases, reference

I wrote:

> Syntactic parsing is a basic task in natural language processing and **the** grammar plays a crucial role in this ??.

First I would like to know how to fill the gap (??). I thought of "regard", "respect", "task", "ground", or nothing and just "this".

Second I don't know if I should use "the grammar" or "grammars" or maybe "grammar" here.

Comment: Syntactic parsing is a basic task in natural language processing and grammar plays a crucial role in such task.

Comment: I think, in this context,grammar is [uncountabel]. Did you already talk about the importance of grammar? If so, I would say there is no problem with using "the".

Comment: @Cardinal no, that is just the first sentence of a paper.

Comment: Note that you don't really have to include *in this (task)*. This is complete enough for me: *Syntactic parsing is a basic task in natural language processing and grammar plays a crucial role.* (I expect that you're going to write more about how grammar plays such an important role right after this sentence, though.)

Comment: "in such task" is not idiomatic.

Comment: Grammar plays a crucial role in the basic task of syntactic parsing of natural language.

Comment: Best not to paint yourself into a corner.

Answer (score 1):

I would omit both the "the" (since you refer to grammar in general) and the "??". You could maybe even use a comma, so that the sentence could be:

> Syntactic parsing is a basic task in natural language processing, and grammar plays a crucial role in this.